# How to draw lines pointing to mouse in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to make a program where there are lines in a grid pointing towards the mouse like magnets. I am a beginner in Processing, can someone point me towards a tutorial on how to do that or give me some code and explain what it does?

```
int x1 = 0;
int x2 = 0;
int y1 = 0;
int y2 = 0;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
}

void draw() {
  background(255, 255, 0);
  x1 = (mouseX + 100) / 2;
  y1 = (mouseY + 100) / 2;
  x2 = -1 * x1 + 200;
  y2 = -1 * y1 + 200;
  line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Comment: Hello! People here are very helpful, but they like you to try your idea first and share your code once you faceplant into a specific problem. If you are looking for a tutorial, there are many ressources out there for Processing. [You can visit the help center to get a better idea of how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Good luck!

Comment: I'm working on an idea, I'll post it when I'm done

Comment: That's the spirit!

Comment: although remember that if you don't have any code yet, it's usually better to delete your question and only post it once you're _actually_ stuck, because questions on SO are not just for you: they're here to help everyone with the same problem, now or in the future. So if your question doesn't actually describe a real problem, it doesn't really belong on Stackoverflow yet.

Comment: Well, I have tried, but I can't figure it out. I know it would use variables, but my only ideas make the line longer.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NKK1-_XThqBpEzJiw49lmEkQ67Xwukngb72pdLr8a2w/edit?usp=sharing

This is my code for the sample. How do I  make the line always the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's plenty of solutions for this project. One of the easiest is to use Processing's [`PVector` class](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html).

> The `PVector` class can be used for two or three dimensional vectors. A **vector** is an entity that has both **magnitude** and **direction**. The `PVector` class, however, stores the components of the vector (x,y for 2D, and x,y,z for 3D). The magnitude and direction are calculated from the components and can be accessed via the methods `mag()` and `heading()`.

A two dimensional vector in Processing is defined through `x` and `y` **components**:

```
PVector v = new PVector(xComponent, yComponent);
```

With some mathematical formulae, you can determine magnitude and direction using the x- and y-components. But we don't need to determine these.

Below, I've attached completed solution code. Most of it should make sense to you. But it's worth understanding what is going on with `PVector`.

A nested `for` loop within `void draw()` contains `x` and `y` variables that represent the coordinates of each grid vertex.

We first define `PVector v` as a vector given by an x-component of `mouseX - x`, or the difference between the x-positions of the mouse and each grid point. Similarly, the y-component given by `mouseY - y` has the same difference.

Creating a variable `PVector u` initialized from `v.setMag(15)` holds a `PVector` that has the same *direction* as `v`, but with a length of just 15.

Now to draw the lines. Vectors represent an *offset*, not a position (in this case), so drawing a line from a grid point to an offset of a grid point is key.

Hence `line(x, y, x + u.x, y + u.y)`, where `u.x` and `u.y` are the x- and y-components of the vector `u`.

---

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 600); // Set the size of the canvas to 600x600.
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  stroke(200); // Set the stroke color to black

  int distVertLine = width / 10; // This variable defines the distance between each subsequent vertical line.
  for(int i = 0; i < width; i += distVertLine) {
    line(i, 0, i, height); // Draw a line at x=i starting at the top of the canvas (y=0) and going to the bottom (y=height)
  }

  int distHorizLine = height / 10; // This variable defines the distance between each subsequent vertical line.
  for(int i = 0; i < width; i += distHorizLine) {
    line(0, i, width, i); // Draw a line at y=i starting at the left of the canvas (x=0) and going to the right (x=width)
  }

  stroke(0); // Set the stroke to black.

  // Use a nested for loop to iterate through all grid vertices.
  for(int x = 0; x <= width; x += width/10) {
    for(int y = 0; y <= height; y += height/10) {
      PVector v = new PVector(mouseX - x, mouseY - y); // Define a vector that points in the direction of the mouse from each grid point.
      PVector u = v.setMag(15); // Make the vector have a length of 15 units.

      line(x, y, x + u.x, y + u.y); // Draw a line from the grid vertex to the terminal point given by the vector.
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the sketch showing lines of fixed length.]

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes sense, I wish I had thought of this. Much less code that I had!

Answer (score 1):

The answer already given by [Ben Myers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12101201/ben-myers) is excellent! The code below has a few small modifications:

- the two for loops for the grid lines have been combined (since width and height are equal);
- the construction of the vector is combined with setting the magnitude;
- some minor changes to colors and comments.

Modified code:

```
void setup() {
  // Set the size of the canvas to 600x600 pixels.
  size(600, 600);
}

void draw() {
  // There are 10x10 grid cells that each have a size of 60x60 pixels.
  int gridSize = width / 10;

  // Set the background color to anthracite and the stroke color to orange.
  background(56, 62, 66);
  stroke(235, 113, 52);

  // Draw vertical and horizontal grid lines.
  for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < gridSize; lineIndex++) {
    line(lineIndex * gridSize, 0, lineIndex * gridSize, height);
    line(0, lineIndex * gridSize, width, lineIndex * gridSize);
  }

  // Set the stroke color to blue.
  stroke(0, 139, 225);

  // Use a nested for loop to iterate through all grid cells.
  for (int x = 0; x <= width; x += gridSize) {
    for (int y = 0; y <= height; y += gridSize) {
      // Define a vector that points in the direction of the mouse from
      // each grid point and set the vector length to 15 units.
      PVector vector = new PVector(mouseX - x, mouseY - y).setMag(15);

      // Draw a line from the grid point to the end point using the vector.
      line(x, y, x + vector.x, y + vector.y);
    }
  }
}
```